# Audited gem to list tracked changes in admin panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin, acts-as-audited

I have created rails application with models: User, InvestmentUpdate and PortfolioContent. I'm using `audited` gem to track changes and list them in admin panel for the models InvestmentUpdate and PortfolioContent. Currently, I am using `rails admin`and found it difficult to list them in admin panel.
Please help me in listing audit track in admin panel.

Comment: Hey! Can you show us what you've tried and didn't work? I used `audit` recently and I may help but I need more context

Comment: I have added  `audited` gem in my Gemfile and then run migration and used `audited` in my two models i.e. `InvestmentUpdate` and `PortfolioContent`. After that, in the console, I tested the audited value and it worked. Now, I have to list it in my admin panel and don't know how to use it.

Comment: I know you already picked audited, but if you change to paper trail the integration is seamless and super easy https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Auditing

Comment: Is there any way to do this with audited??

Comment: I am facing same issue, how did you display the changes in your view pages @user012

Comment: @chrisgeeq I switched to paper trail gem to list in rails-admin panel https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Auditing, integration is super easy with a paper trail.